# Low speed when download S3 Object by wget or cURL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I noticed that when using aws-cli to download an S3 object, the download speed can reach almost 2Gb. But when I use cURL or wget to download the object, the download speed only can reach at 100MB/s.

The aws-cli may separate the object and download it parallel. But is there any way to speed up the cURL or wget download speed?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) can use **multi-part downloads** to download content in parallel. This involves multiple API calls to AWS.

However, `curl` and `wget` use traditional HTTP requests that cannot operate in parallel.

If you have a lot of data to download from Amazon S3, either use the AWS CLI or [AWS DataSync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/what-is-datasync.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. so is it normal that the speed only can reached 100MB/s when using `curl` or `wget` to download the S3 object?

Comment: Not sure! You'd have to try from various different networks to identify the bottleneck. It would also be related to round-trip time (ping time) since packets need to be acknowledged. Using a closer region or downloading via CloudFront will likely improve the speed.